# Encog One Of - decode

Tags: encog

I am using Encog in one of the project and i got stuck while deocding One-Of class.
One of the field's Normalization Action is NormalizationAction.OneOf which have three output. When i evaluate, i want to decode the predicted value.  how to decode...?

```
 var eq = new Encog.MathUtil.Equilateral(classCount, normalizationHigh, normalizationLow);
var predictedClassInt = eq.Decode(output);
```

The above code is for Equilateral. How can i do the same for One-Of.

Thanks,
Kans

Answer (score 5):

Here is sample code (in C#) for decoding one-of-n encoded classes.

> var outputIndex = EngineArray.MaxIndex(output);
>
> var classOutput = analyst.Script.Normalize.NormalizedFields[index].Classes[outputIndex].Name;

Means,you get the output array using `Network.Compute()` first.Then you try to find out, which element in the output array has the maximum value `(The Winner)`. Then you can use that index and the analyst information to get the class name.

So you can use your analyst class. If you have persisted you analyst file, then you can load it to memory using

> var analyst = new EncogAnalyst();
>
> analyst.Load(AnalystFilePath.ToString());